# How to convert "sourceSet" of Groovy -> Kotlin DSL (Gradle)?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, groovy, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Here is the sourceSet which I want to convert into Kotlin Gradle DSL. Basically it excludes all other directories inside `src/main/resources/` except 'templates' and 'fonts'.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            include 'templates/*'
            include 'assets/fonts/*'
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I've tried till now:

```kotlin
sourceSets.create("main") {
    resources.srcDir {
        include("templates/*")
        include("assets/fonts/*")
    }
}
```

But `include` doesn't seem to resolve the reference here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've successfully managed to do it like this.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
             srcDir("templates")
             srcDir("assets/fonts/")
        }
    }
}
```